# running update statment with Where condition on same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of items:

```
itemid  quantity unitid  baseunitid
 880      5        10    null
 881      5         5    null
```

table of units:

```
unitid unittypeid 
 10       1
  5       1
  4       1
```

lets assume that 10 is KM, 5 is Meters and 4 is cm.

table of unittypes:

```
unittypeid baseunitid
 1         4
```

That means that the unittypeid 1 contains a goup of length units an their base unit  in my system is `unitid=4` which is `cm`.

I want to write a query which pass over `items` and update the `basunit` column to the basic unit as appears in `baseunitid`.

meaning I want to get:

```
itemid  quantity unitid  baseunit
 10      5        10     4
 11      5         5     4
```

I wrote this query:

```
update items a set baseunitid = (select baseunitid
                                     from unittypes
                                     where unittypeid=(select unittypeid
                                                      from units
                                                      where unitid=a.unitid)
```

However this doesn't work as I can't refer `a.unitid` in the subquery.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a `FROM` clause:

```
update items i
    set baseunitid = ut.baseunitid
    from units u join
         unittypes ut
         on ut.unittypeid = u.unittypeid
    where i.unitid = u.unitid;
```

However, I would advise you *not* to keep this information in two tables.  Instead, use a query, view, or function to extract the information.  This will prevent problems should the base units change.